Does it depend on context whether it can be seen or is able to see by itself?
While learning I came accross this sentence on WaniKani:
あそこの村人は見えますか？
I read it as "Can this villager over there see?". However, the given translation was "Can you see this villager over there."
I went to Google translate and tried other variatons:
あそこの村人は見ることができますか？
あの村人は見ることができますか？
Those too came back as "Can you see this villager over there."
However when I translated "Can this villager over there see?" from english to Japanese with Google translate I got the following:
向こうの村人は見えますか？
Therefore I get the impression that grammar doesn't tell me whether the villager can see or can be seen. In this case it would be context dependent what I understand.
I guess it is similar to 山の中に住んでいる which, because of missing plurals in Japanese, can be "living inside a mountain" or "living in the mountains".
Two Questions:

Is my assumption correct and it is context dependent whether something can see or can be seen?
If we want to be precise rather than sound normal, how would we make a grammatical difference between my two sample sentences?


Can you see this villager over there.
Can this villager over there see?


There are two grammar points involved:

は is a topic marker, not a subject marker nor an object marker. Japanese is a topic-prominent language. That means, は may mark a subject, an object or something else. For example, 寿司は食べますか almost certainly means "Will you eat sushi?" rather than "Will sushi eat it?". This may sound absurd if you're thinking only in terms of English grammar, but this is how Japanese works, as well as other east-Asian languages.

When a potential form (such as 見られる, 見える and 食べられる) is used, the "object" can be marked with が. For example, even when は is not used, 星が見える and 星が見られる almost certainly mean "Stars are visible / We can see stars" rather than "The star can see it". This is why some people say Japanese potential verbs are actually close to English potential adjectives such as "edible", "visible" and "drinkable". See: The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb


Therefore, あそこの村人は見えますか is indeed an ambiguous sentence that may mean either "Can you see the villager over there?" or "Can the villager over there see it?". When there is no further context, the former is definitely the more likely interpretation, so you need to get used to this pattern. However, if the context is about many villagers who are watching something from various places, exactly the same sentence would mean "Can the villager over there see it?".

If we want to be precise rather than sound normal, how would we make a grammatical difference between my two sample sentences?

This type of disambiguation is rarely necessary, but you can use a nominalizer like this:

Can you see the villager over there?
あそこの村人を見ることはできますか？
Can the villager over there see it?
あそこの村人が(それを)見ることはできますか？
Can the sushi eat it?
寿司が(それを)食べることはできますか？
(Semantically weird, but this always means the sushi is the eater)


from your answer I infer that adding an object makes it pecise.
If we make the villager the object by adding を to it we know that the villager is the "thing" that can be seen. However if we make something that can be seen the object (like 何か or 何も) we know that it is about the villagers ability to see.
Therefore this would be unambiguous: またくあの審判は何もを見えませんよ。--> Tse, that referee doesn't see a damn thing.

@MerlinNestler If you mean a sentence like "あそこの村人を見えますか?", this unfortunately is not natural. It's better to think of 見える as an intransitive verb that means "to be visible" or "can be seen".
